# Listview shows only one row at a time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

I am having a problem with a list view that will only show one row at a time even though there are many rows. 
The list view is included within a tab so the problem could be there rather than in the list view.
I first tried defining the list view in a separate layout file and using that when creating the tab. When that didn't work I put it into the FrameLayout with the tab definition.
Same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
            </ListView></FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is the code I use to create and add the tab:

```
protected void addTab(String tabName, TabHost.TabContentFactory tabFactory){
    TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
    tabSpec.setContent(tabFactory);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    tabs.add(new TabDetails(tabName,tabFactory));

}
```

I call it with:

```
addTab("Medical Center Tests",this);
```

and include this code for creating the tab contents:

```
@Override
public View createTabContent(String tag) {


    // Get the data returned from the servelet and display it in the ListView
    data = getDataArray(this.getIntent().getExtras());




    ListView lv = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.list1);

lv.setAdapter(new MyMedicalCentersTestsScreenAdapter(this,lv,data));
return lv;
}
```

The data is all there. It's just the the height of the list view is equal to the height of one row.

**EDIT**:

I added some debug commands to see what position the getView requests. It only requests the first row and then requests them one at a time as I scroll.
So, it is definitely seeing it as a small listview and scrolling them accordingly.

**Edit 2**:

Decided to try an experiment.
Returned a simple list for the list view.

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    // create some dummy strings to add to the list
    List<String> list1Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1Strings.add("Item 1");
    list1Strings.add("Item 2");
    list1Strings.add("Item 3");
    list1Strings.add("Item 4");
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1Strings));
```

Still the same. Only one row at a time.

Comment: I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess it's because you put your ListView in a FrameLayout. Try a vertically oriented LinearLayout instead for your "@android:id/tabcontent"

Comment: can you scroll it to view the other items? or it just shows a single item?

Comment: I've seen it in a number of examples exactly like that.

Comment: I can scroll to them all. It just seems to create the listview to the height of one entry.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

`<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TabWidget>`

instead of

`<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TabWidget>`

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` or `android:layout_height="100dp"`

instead of this

`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: That just affects the text of the tab header. Not the list within the tab.

Comment: Sorry, but the list is within a tab? For example tab1? Your layout set the list below tabs.

Comment: Weird. It is within the list. Something happened when I copied the code. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you define height of layout rather than using fill_parent...

code:

```
 layout_height ="150dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is a little weird cause the tabWidget (it displays a list of tab labels representing each page in the parent's tab collection) height is set to `fill_parent`. How about something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/tabhost">
<LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="84dp" >

</TabWidget>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </LinearLayout>

  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

For tabs:

```
    tabhost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabhost.setup();

    TabSpec ts = tabhost.newTabSpec("tag1"); 
    ts.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    ts.setIndicator("TAB1");
    tabhost.addTab(ts);

    ts = tabhost.newTabSpec("tag2"); 
    ts.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    ts.setIndicator("TAB2");  
    tabhost.addTab(ts);
```

You add tabs in that way 'cause you add them dynamically?

Comment: I add the tabs that way because I attach an Adapter to them. Easiest way to do it is via a TabFactory. I tried changing the layout like you gave but to no avail.